# Mosquitto + Raspberry Pi 4 | Error: Problem Setting TLS options

Tags: raspberry-pi, mqtt, mosquitto, raspberry-pi4

I'm trying to set up a Mosquitto with certificates but can't seem to get it to work.

I'm following a guide for a project I'm doing but now I'm stuck here..
I'm on a Raspberry Pi4 with Raspberry Pi OS kernel 4.19.
The error occurs when I'm about to do a mosquitto_pub

```
 mosquitto_pub -h 127.0.0.1 --cafile ~/certs/ca.crt -p 8883 -t "test" -m "Hello World" -r -- tls-version tlsv1
```

and the return I get is: Error: Problem setting TLS options.

This is what I've done so far:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/owntracks/tools/master/TLS/generate-CA.sh


pico generate-CA.sh
```

> Uncomment and change the following lines, use your server IP and hostname
>
>   IPLIST="192.168.10.125" 
> HOSTLIST="icserver"

> Save the file (CTRL+x), add execution rights to the script and run it.
>
> `chmod +x generate-CA.sh`
>
> `./generate-CA.sh`

> Copy the SSL certificates to the right place for Mosquitto (if you used another server name (not icserver), as in this guide the files will have other names)

```
sudo cp ca.crt /etc/mosquitto/certs/
sudo cp icserver.crt /etc/mosquitto/certs/
sudo cp icserver.key /etc/mosquitto/certs/
```

> Make the Mosquitto config file

```
sudo pico /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/icserver.conf
```

> 

```
user mosquitto

queue_qos0_messages false
persistent_client_expiration 2h
allow_duplicate_messages false
protocol mqtt
listener 8883
cafile /etc/mosquitto/certs/ca.crt
certfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/icserver.crt
keyfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/icserver.key tls_version tlsv1

autosave_interval 1800
allow_anonymous true
```

Save the file (CTRL+x) and restart the Mosquitto server

```
sudo service mosquitto restart
```

Check that the Mosquitto server is running

```
ps aux | grep mosquito
```

Should output something like this if the server is running
mosquit+ 1094 0.0 0.4 8232 4620 ? S 15:44 0:00 /usr/sbin/mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf
pi 1102 0.0 0.0 4372 560 pts/0 S+ 15:45 0:00 grep --color=auto mosquito

Now try to publish something to the server to check that it works (everything must be on the same line)

```
mosquitto_pub -h 127.0.0.1 --cafile ~/certs/ca.crt -p 8883 -t "test" -m "Hello World" -r -- tls-version tlsv1
```

No output means that it works, now try to subscribe to the message we sent.

```
mosquitto_sub -h 127.0.0.1 --cafile ~/certs/ca.crt -p 8883 -t "test" --tls-version tlsv1
```

Comment: What does the Mosquitto log file say?  Does it show the client connecting, but not successfully?

Comment: How do I check?

Comment: I believe the default log file is ``/var/log/mosquitto.log``.  This is a good article on Mosquitto logging: http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/mosquitto-logging/